# grep error without error message

Tags: bash, grep

I have a (long) Bash script that do something like this:

```
set -o nounset
set -o errexit
set -o pipefail

echo -e "foo \n bar" | grep "baz" | tr -d ' '

echo "here"
```

The script fails without error message, because the grep command returns error 1 without printing any error message.

How to make my script robust?

Comment: From the `grep` man page: "EXIT STATUS
     The grep utility exits with one of the following values:
     0     One or more lines were selected.
     1     No lines were selected.
     >1    An error occurred."  So an exit value of 1 just means the string was not found (as expected), not that an error occurred.

Comment: What output do you expect in case of string not found in grep?

Comment: `grep` doesn't write any error if match isn't found.

Comment: Bentoy13: I expect no output, but I want this case to be considered by my script like an error, and managed properly.

Comment: @user744629 `set -e` ?

Comment: set -e is the same as set -errexit

Answer (score 2):

You can use `grep -q` and check its return status:

```
if $(echo -e "foo \n bar" | grep -q "baz"); then
    echo "grep success"
else
    echo "grep failure"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

`grep` would produce a non-zero exit code if the pattern fails to match.  Moreover, it'd not produce any *error message*.  In order to obtain a error message if the pattern is not found in the input, you'd need an alternative.  You might use `awk`:

```
echo -e "foo \n bar" | \
awk 'BEGIN{f=0}/baz/{f=1;print;}END{if (!f) {print "Error; string not found"; exit 1;}}' | \
tr -d ' '
```

This would behave pretty similar to `grep` (in terms of exit code) and would produce the error message if the match is not found.

In order to output the error message to `STDERR`, you can say:

```
echo -e "foo \n bar" | \
awk 'BEGIN{f=0}/baz/{f=1;print;}END{if (!f) {print "Error; string not found" > "/dev/stderr"; exit 1;}}' | \
tr -d ' '
```